# C++ - Updating value in pointer gets overridden

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, copy-constructor, move-constructor

I've recently begun learning C++ and I'm having some trouble updating a pointer in my `Movie` class. I've got a feeling I have an issue somewhere in my Move/Copy constructors but have been trying to solve this issue for hours, swapping pointers to references to values and finally coming here for help.

I have a class `Movie`, which contains a string name, string rating and int watched member variables. Another class `Movies`, holds a vector of the movies. On movie, my method `increment_watched` is supposed to increment the int watched by one, the value *does* get incremented but it seems like the value is not saved. The `display_all_movies` method in Movies, which simply displays the movies that it stores holds the old value for watched. I know the issue is probably something really small but I haven't been able to work out why the value isn't being saved.

If someone could explain why the pointer value seems to be getting overridden I'd appreciate it greatly. Thanks in advance!

Code is below, there is some debug couts in there.

Movie.h

```
#ifndef _MOVIE_H_
#define _MOVIE_H_
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Movie {
private:
    std::string *name;
    std::string *rating;
    int *watched;
public:
    std::string get_name();
    std::string get_rating();
    int get_watched();
    void increment_watched();
    Movie(std::string name, std::string rating, int watched_val); // normal constructor
    Movie(const Movie &source); // copy constructor
    Movie(Movie &&source); // move constructor
    ~Movie();

};

#endif // _MOVIE_H_
```

Movie.cpp

```
#include "Movie.h"

std::string Movie::get_name() {
    return *name;
}

std::string Movie::get_rating() {
    return *rating;
}

int Movie::get_watched() {
    return *watched;
}

void Movie::increment_watched() {
    std::cout << *watched << std::endl;
    (*watched)++; // TODO FIX!
    std::cout << *watched << std::endl;
}

Movie::Movie(std::string name, std::string rating, int watched_val) 
    : name{nullptr}, rating{nullptr}, watched{nullptr}{   
    std::cout << "Creating movie " << watched_val << " with normal constructor" << std::endl; 
    this->name = new std::string{name};
    this->rating = new std::string{rating};
    this->watched = new int{watched_val};

}

Movie::Movie(const Movie &source) 
    : Movie(*source.name, *source.rating, *source.watched) {
        std::cout << "Creating movie " << *source.watched << " with copy constructor" << std::endl; 

}

Movie::Movie(Movie &&source)
    : Movie(*source.name, *source.rating, *source.watched) {
        std::cout << "Creating movie " << *source.watched << " with move constructor" << std::endl; 
        source.name = nullptr;
        source.rating = nullptr;
        source.watched = nullptr;
}

Movie::~Movie() {
        delete name;
        delete rating;
        delete watched;
}
```

Movies.h

```
#ifndef _MOVIES_H_
#define _MOVIES_H_
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Movie.h"

class Movies {
private:
    static int count;
    std::vector<Movie> *movies;
public:
    void add_movie(std::string &&name, std::string &&rating, int &&watch);
    void increment_movie_count(std::string &&name);
    void display_all_movies();
    void count_movies();
    Movies();
    Movies(const Movie &source); // copy constructor
    Movies(Movie &&source); // move constructor
    ~Movies();

};

#endif // _MOVIES_H_
```

Movies.cpp

```
#include "Movies.h"

int Movies::count = 0;

void Movies::add_movie(std::string &&name, std::string &&rating, int &&watch) {
    bool contains {false};

    for(auto movie : *movies) {
        if(movie.get_name() == name) {
            contains = true;
        }
    }
    if(!contains) {
        movies->push_back(Movie{name, rating, watch});
        count++;
    }
}

void Movies::increment_movie_count(std::string &&name) {
    for(auto movie : *movies) {
        if(movie.get_name() == name) {
            movie.increment_watched();
        }
    }

}

void Movies::display_all_movies() {
    for(auto movie : *movies) {
        std::cout << "Title " << movie.get_name() << " Rating " << movie.get_rating() << " Watched " << movie.get_watched() << std::endl;
    }
}

void Movies::count_movies() {
    std::cout << "There are " << count << " movies " << std::endl; 
}

Movies::Movies() {
    movies = new std::vector<Movie>{};
}

Movies::~Movies() {
    delete movies;
}
```

And finally main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Movies.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {

    Movies *my_movies;


    my_movies = new Movies();

    (*my_movies).count_movies();

    my_movies->add_movie("Big", "PG-13", 2);
    my_movies->increment_movie_count("Big");

    my_movies->display_all_movies();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you use pointers everywhere? In your code there is no obvious reason for using a single pointer

Comment: If you've just begun learning C++, please learn "proper" C++ and do not use raw pointers (not at this point in time)! Also avoid rvalue references `&&` if you don't know what they do! I suggest you change your tutorial/teacher/learning resource as quick as possible!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are dynamically allocating everything?

Comment: Recommended reading: [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Comment: FWIW, I really support this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk

Comment: Use `&` in range-based for.

Comment: Also recommended: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). It's rare that an identifier like `_MOVIES_H_` will cause you problems, but when it does, the error messages and program behaviour are utterly bizarre.

Comment: Side note: your move constructor is wrong, if I'm not mistaken. It leaks memory.

Comment: Also, don't use pointers unless completely necessary. It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Your move constructor has to call an allocation function three times (because it invokes `Movie(*source.name, *source.rating, *source.watched)`). Nothing has actually been moved, everything has been copied, defeating the entire point of using pointers.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I was under the impression for non-primative types pointers should be used? as it is more efficient to pass the pointer than to copy the value?

Comment: @andreee thanks for the advice! I'm actually currently doing a course, I know the lectures on smart pointers are coming up, but I guess they've decided to teach raw pointers first. I've only used rvalue references for my move constructor here, is my implementation incorrect? or is it that these shouldn't be used and am being taught outdated concepts?

Comment: thats only partly correct, but to keep it simple: This is wrong. Especially for your members there is no point in using pointers. When you want to avoid copies you pass references around

Comment: @user4581301 interesting thanks for the link. I've been taught that I should always define my header files _CLASS_H_ and that it's common practice

Comment: `CLASS_H` is fine. `_CLASS_H` is not. Violates the no `_<capital letter>` prefix at any scope rule (and the `_` prefix at file scope rule, not that it matters).

Comment: I would say that the resources are outdates. And in any case, I wouldn't consider rvalue references a topic for a beginner's C++ introduction...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change`for(auto movie : *movies)`  to `for(auto& movie : *movies)` to update the original movie objects. Otherwise, you're only updating copies of the movie objects.